# Create an array, based on the values of an existing array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reduce

I have an array of objects as follows.

```
 const arr = [
    {
      categoryId: "I01",
      categoryName: "Category_one",
      price: 100
    },
    {
      categoryId: "I02",
      categoryName: "Category_two",
      price: 200
    },
    {
      categoryId: "I03",
      categoryName: "Category_three",
      price: 300
    },
    {
      categoryId: "I02",
      categoryName: "Category_two",
      price: 210
    },
    {
      categoryId: "I03",
      categoryName: "Category_three",
      price: 310
    }
 ]
```

And I am working in order to have a result as follows. It is like filtering the whole array base on categories.

```
arr2 = [
    {
      id: 0,
      categoryId: "I01",
      categoryName: "Category_one",
      minimum_price: 100,
      count: 1
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      categoryId: "I02",
      categoryName: "Category_two",
      minimum_price: 200,
      count: 2
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      categoryId: "I03",
      categoryName: "Category_three",
      minimum_price: 300,
      count: 2
    },
]
```

I have created the result up to below level

```
const resArr = [];
    arr.forEach((item) => {
        let i = resArr.findIndex(x => x.categoryId == item.categoryId);
        if (i <= -1) {
            resArr.push({ categoryId: item.categoryId, categoryName: item.categoryName });
        }
    });
    resArr.forEach((o, i) => o.id = i);
```

And got this result,

```
 res = [
        {
          id: 0,
          categoryId: "I01",
          categoryName: "Category_one"
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          categoryId: "I02",
          categoryName: "Category_two"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          categoryId: "I03",
          categoryName: "Category_three"
        },
    ]
```

I need to have minimum_price value and count values. highly appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) along with [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
let id = -1;

// Even though we're reducing to an object, Object.values will
// extract the result to an array.
const result = Object.values(arr.reduce(({
  categoryId,
  categoryName,
  price,
}, acc) => {
  // If we don't already have something from that
  // category, make a new entry in the hash
  if (!(categoryId in acc)) acc[categoryId] = {
    categoryId,
    categoryName,
    minPrice: price,
    id: id++, // increment the id
    count: 0,
  };

  // Increase the count for that category by 1
  acc[categoryId].count += 1;

  // Set new minimum price if applicable
  if (acc[categoryId].price > price) acc[categoryId].price = price;

  // return the accumulator
  return acc;
}, {}));
```

Comment: Hi @Jared Smith, I checked with my data, but couldn't get the result as expected with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

firstly, apply the `id` field:

```js
arr.map(item=>({...item, id: Number(item.categoryId.slice(1))}))
```

And turn it into an (effectively) `Map<int, Category>`, you can use either an `Array` or a `Map`, but you should know this may not be the final array you want, because it might be sparse.

(and you can merge the former step with this):

```js
const map = [];
for(const item of arr) {
  const id = Number(item.categoryId.slice(1))
  if(!map[id]) {
    map[id] = {
        id,
        categoryId: item.categoryId,
        categoryName: item.categoryName,
        minimum_price: item.price,
        count: 1
    }
  } else {
    map[id].count += 1
    map[id].minimum_price = Math.min(map[id].minimum_price, item.price)
  }
}
```

And make it the final array you want. You may just filter out the empty slots:

```js
return map.filter(Boolean)
```

And I would highly recommend you to keep `id` consistent with `categoryId`. It could be confusing to have sth. like `{id: 0, categoryId: 'I01'}`.

And this is what you would get (JSON stringified):

```json
[{"id":1,"categoryId":"I01","categoryName":"Category_one","minimum_price":100,"count":1},{"id":2,"categoryId":"I02","categoryName":"Category_two","minimum_price":200,"count":2},{"id":3,"categoryId":"I03","categoryName":"Category_three","minimum_price":300,"count":2}]
```

---

> can you update your answer when the "categoryId" doesn't contain any integer

It depends on whether you still want a meaningful `id` field.
If not, the map should be a `Map<string, Category>` instead (or an object):

```js
const map = {};
for(const item of arr) {
  if(!map[item.categoryId]) {
    map[item.categoryId] = {
        categoryId: item.categoryId,
        categoryName: item.categoryName,
        minimum_price: item.price,
        count: 1
    }
  } else {
    map[item.categoryId].count += 1
    map[item.categoryId].minimum_price = Math.min(map[id].minimum_price, item.price)
  }
}
```

And you would need to turn map into an array, which can be done by `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, `Object.entries`, or a `for...in` loop:

```js
Object.values(map)
```

And apply the `id` field if you still want it:

```js
Object.values(map).map((v, id) => ({...v, id}))
```

---

Or, if you want a meaningful `id` field,

You will have to find a way to map the categoryId into an integer somehow.

Comment: Hi, @Yongjian Wang, The answer is quite supportive, but can you update your answer when the "categoryId" doesn't contain any integer.